# How to improve performance of Solr query related to spatial searching?

Tags: java, solr, query-performance, spatial-query

So I'm attempting to write a Solr query that will do some spatial searching. However the query that I am attempting to run has a few thousand coordinates that I want to search.

I have tried to run this query:

`fq=({!geofilt pt=lat,long sfield=geo d=num} OR {!geofilt pt=lat2,long2 sfield=geo d=num}...OR...)`

However the query times out when I try running it, I'm assuming due to how large the query is. I have tried splitting up the query and running separate queries and I'm able to run those, but I do not get my expected result because the queries return objects that match multiple queries and therefore it causes an overlap.

Can anyone recommend any strategies as to how I can run this query efficiently?

Comment: What field type are you currently using? The [RPT field type](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/spatial-search.html#SpatialSearch-RPT) supports a few tweakable parameters (`distErrPct`, `maxDistErr`), and can index polygons etc. Depending on the meaning of your query lat/lon/d, it could be possible to set these values when indexing and instead query against the polygons around those points - it's hard to say without knowing what problem you're trying to solve by having a couple of thousand coordinates in your query.

Comment: @MatsLindh I am trying to find users whose locations are inside the radius (num) of the latitude (lat) and longitude (long) in the parameters.